# Getting pandas new indexing "loc" and "iloc" to work with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

Using PyInstaller (tested with 2.0 and dev version), I package the below code as an .exe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
print df.iloc[0]
```

When I run the executable, I end up getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\pyinstaller-2.0\Hello\build\pyi.win32\Hello\out00-PYZ.pyz\pandas.core.frame", line 1879, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

If I replace `iloc` with the older `ix`, everything works as it should so I'm suspecting that PyInstaller can't find/use the latest version of pandas. How can I get PyInstaller to work with `iloc` as well?

I'm using Python 2.7.4 and pandas 0.11.0 via WinPython on Windows 7.

Comment: iloc should be in 0.11 btw: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#selection-choices

Comment: Yeah, my code works fine when running it in the interpreter. It's only when packaging with PyInstaller that the problem arises.

Comment: perhaps you could do a test program and print pd.version.version ?

Comment: smart... that returns 0.9.1. and it also reminded me that i installed Enthought and Python(x,y) a long time back. I will remove them and see if it helps.

Comment: After rinsing all old python installations, I have gotten past this problem. Thank you! (new PyInstaller/pandas problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512167/pyinstaller-onefile-throws-qt-error-with-pandas-matplotlib-and-sklearn in case you have gotten any tips for that one as well)