# Pyinstaller --onefile warning pyconfig.h when importing scipy or scipy.signal

Tags: scipy, pyinstaller

This is very simple to recreate.
If my script foo.py is:

```
import scipy
```

Then run:

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile foo.py
```

When I launch foo.exe I get:

```
WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI86402\Include\pyconfig.h
```

I've tested a few versions but the latest I've confirmed is 2.1dev-e958e02 running on Win7, Python 2.7.5 (32 bit), Scipy version 0.12.0

I've submitted a ticket with the Pyinstaller folks but haven't heard anything yet. Any clues how to debug this further?

Comment: This problem doesn't occur in PyInstaller 3.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can hack the spec file to remove the second instance by adding these lines after a=Analysis:

```
for d in a.datas:
    if 'pyconfig' in d[0]: 
        a.datas.remove(d)
        break
```

Comment: Sadly this workaround didn't work for me. It got rid of the "file already exists" error, but now the --onefile executable just crashes without any warning. I'll fiddle with it some more and see if I can't figure something out.

Comment: @dthor, did you ever get this resolved?  I seem to be stuck the same place.

Answer (score 15):

The answer by wtobia@ worked for me. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/783

1. Go to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py`
2. Find the `def append(self, tpl):` function.
3. Change `if tpl[2] == "BINARY":` to `if tpl[2] in ["BINARY", "DATA"]:`

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Comment: link is dead; perhaps see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/783 instead

Comment: It looks like this issue is fixed in the development version, but they haven't put out [a release](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases) since 2013. The workaround by [scornwell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20695056/4794) worked for me.

Comment: This problem doesn't occur in PyInstaller 3.4

Answer (score 7):

Expanding upon Ilya's solution, I think this is a little bit more robust solution to modifying the spec file (again place after the a=Analysis... statement).

```
a.datas = list({tuple(map(str.upper, t)) for t in a.datas})
```

I only tested this on a small test program (one with a single import and print statement), but it seems to work.  a.datas is a list of tuples of strings which contain the pyconfig.h paths.  I convert them all to lowercase and then dedup.  I actually found that converting all of them all to lowercase was sufficient to get it to work, which suggests to me that pyinstaller does case-sensitive deduping when it should be case-insensitive on Windows.  However, I did the deduping myself for good measure.

Comment: your suggestion works on windows but fails on linux. just fyi.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the problem would even happen on Linux, so you wouldn't need a solution.  Have you had this problem on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the problem is that Windows is case-insensitive and these 2 statements are source directories are "duplicates:
include\pyconfig.h
Include\pyconfig.h

My solution is to manually tweak the .spec file with after the a=Analysis() call:

```
import platform
if platform.system().find("Windows")>= 0:
    a.datas = [i for i in a.datas if i[0].find('Include') < 0]
```

This worked in my 2 tests.

A more flexible solution would be to check ALL items for case-insensitive collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the archive_viewer.py utility (from PyInstaller) on one of my own --onefile executables that has the same error and found that pyconfig.h is included twice:

```
 (31374007, 6521, 21529, 1, 'x', 'include\\pyconfig.h'),
 (31380528, 6521, 21529, 1, 'x', 'Include\\pyconfig.h'),
 (31387049, 984, 2102, 1, 'x', 'pytz\\zoneinfo\\CET'),
```

Sadly though, I don't know how to fix it.

PyInstaller Manual link:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html#archiveviewer