# Pyinstaller --onefile warning pyconfig.h, finding other solutions

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

using the following libraries and pyinstaller-2.1 on windows OS to create a executable in onefile, i got a warning message.

my script `foo.py`

```
import gdal
import ogr
import osr
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from liblas import file
from laspy import file
```

Process it by pyinstaller.py:

```
$ python pyinstaller.py --onefile foo.py
```

I get the error message

```
WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI86402\Include\pyconfig.h
```

I used all solutions in this link [Pyinstaller --onefile warning pyconfig.h when importing scipy or scipy.signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055089/pyinstaller-onefile-warning-pyconfig-h-when-importing-scipy-or-scipy-signal) but i still get the error message