# pyinstaller issues with --onefile and --onedir

Tags: python, user-interface, compilation, executable, pyinstaller

I am aware that there are several other topics address this issue, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583611/pyinstaller-newbie-hello-world), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055089/pyinstaller-onefile-warning-pyconfig-h-when-importing-scipy-or-scipy-signal). Despite having tried all of the suggested solutions in those topics, I am still getting that file already exists error with pyinstaller. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNR7n.jpg) is how I edited the spec file and that didn't work. After getting dll errors with py2exe I thought I'd try pyinstaller which can at least finish compiling my simple program unlike py2exe, but now I'm having this error with pyinstaller and none of the solutions I found worked for me.

These are the issues I'm having with --onefile distribution. With --onedir, it compiles my program and when I double click the .exe, it doesn't give me any errors, but it just doesn't do anything. No errors but also no window. I'm completely stuck here and will appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: run the exe from command prompt and see if there is any error

Comment: no errors, no output, no warnings. just nothing.

Comment: did you provide any print statement in the python code did it work well when it was a python code provide code example

Comment: No my program doesn't have any print statements, it doesn't print anything. It has two modules, one for GUI(Tkinter) and one for some background calculations. What it does is, you start the gui module and enter some values, make some selections from dropdown menus and hit a start button, and it calls for the calculator module and then gui plots the outcome of the calculations. Embedded plotting that is. So it has only one window with entry boxes and labels and tabs and a canvas, basically. It imports matplotlib, numpy, xlrd and tkinter.

Comment: did it work when it was run as a python programm

Comment: I've been testing it for days now, it works without any problems when run as a .py file. By the way I've added a simple print statement in the beginning of the program and compiled again. It does not print the string.

Comment: if you could provide the sample program with out that I cant understand your problem

Comment: I've made a sample program for a shorter/simplified version, which basically does what my program does. And I am having the exact same errors with compiling this sample program. [Here](http://pastebin.com/iPs3dtgP) is the source. Note: try to enter "integers" higher than say 5 in that entry box.

Answer (score 0):

There is no output in the console because you have set

```
console = False
```

in your spec file. 
Try to compile using

```
console = True
```

then you will be able to see the errors.