# RunFrozenPython in xlwings complains on Workbook.caller() in Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I have a script in Python copying values from one spreadsheet to another.
It runs well with RunPython
When I try using RunFrozenPython it is giving this exception
[image: xlwings thinks the caller is not excel, what can I do so it thinks the caller is Excel like when I use the RunPython command successfully.]

xlwings thinks the caller is not excel, what can I do so it thinks the caller is Excel? just how RunPython does successfully.

Before I get the exception , I do get a warning , here is the snapshot. The script waits until I click OK and then errors out as shown above.

Here is the warning message, the location shown does not exist on my machine -

[image]

Comment: What has VBA/Excel-VBA got to do with it?

Comment: Try to upgrade both, the xlwings VBA module and the Python package to 0.4.0 and see if that helps...

Comment: I am using Excel-VBA to call a Python script which references the calling workbook using xlwings.Workbook.caller() method, which is erroring out, hence Excel-VBA / VBA

Comment: I just upgraded to 0.4.0 and included the the bas file in my vba script, getting same error. Using Python 2.7.9. Your help is much appreciated Felix.

Comment: The exe file is created using Pyinstaller

Comment: The warning is from PyInstaller: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19055089/918626

Answer (score 0):

I got the error resolved by using `wb = Workbook("path to file")`

instead of using `wb = Workbook.caller()`

This way the excel is not referenced by the caller but by its absolute path.

I could still use help resolving the warning :)

Comment: That's not what you should be doing as this will break as soon as you move your spreadsheet or rename it. Posting a minimal code sample that will reproduce the error will help. I have never looked at freezing with PyInstaller though, only with cx_Freeze, so maybe that's part of the issue.