# Pyinstaller QtCore Module import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, pyinstaller

I am trying to build my app with --onefile option by pyinstaller. Here is the extract.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from modules.login import Login

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    login = Login()
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to build using:

```
 >pyinstaller --onefile app.py
```

Running the generated dist/app I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

I am building this from Ubuntu 13. Anyone with an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`

Comment: Running .. > libqt4-dev is already the newest version

Comment: Yes.It is installed and I can run the program well before building with the Pyinstaller.

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: I have decide to build everything from source. I will let you know the results> http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html#configuring-pyqt4

Comment: did you try using --onedir instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried --onedir it did not work. Building from source does not help too.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bug in the current version of PyInstaller that causes this problem. See this [ticket](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/864) for more details.

The good news is that it's been fixed. The bad news is that it's only arriving in PyInstaller 2.2. In the mean time, you could try installing a development build of PyInstaller to solve this issue.

Comment: Installing the development version worked for me too. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631157/pyside-and-pyqt-clash-when-packaging-pylab-under-windows-7

Comment: How do you install PyInstaller 2.2 in Ubuntu?

Comment: You need to download the source package from [GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki) and install it. It's a case of uncompress source archive, then run `python setup.py build` followed by `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

i just had a similar problem, once i ran pyinstaller --onedir main.py, i got that error.

i copied the Qt5core.dll in the same folder as the generated .exe to the \PyQt\bin folder and everything was working well.