# Pyinstaller, Pyside issue on Linux

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a exe for Ubuntu with pyinstaller and hit an error after it successfully builds.

```
My error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

In my app I use from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

My spec file looks like:

```
 -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['/home/tom/NJM_GUI.py'],
         pathex=['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/', '/home/tom'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='NJM_GUI',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
```

I built it like this:

```
pyinstaller -F '/home/tom/NJM_GUI.py'  -p '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/'
```

What do I do to fix this issue? Exe gets built fine but seems to be missing this module.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Same issue here, running on Windows (with msys)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pyinstaller QtCore Module import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709651/pyinstaller-qtcore-module-import-error)